# Bootstrap caroussel not sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to add a slideshow to my webpage using Bootstrap Caroussel, but seems that the photos is not sliding, only showing the first picture. And the buttons in the bottom and on both sides are not working well. Any one would like to look at my code and help me with this?

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/reverse1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/12976329_224255987939469_1210159874_n.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/13098983_106200126454398_1338693822_n.jpg" width="450" height="450">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/13166635_879641332146032_791969762_n.jpg" width="450" height="450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `bootstrap.min.js`

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2014/2-black-wallpaper-pattern.preview.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2014/2-black-wallpaper-pattern.preview.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2014/2-black-wallpaper-pattern.preview.jpg" width="450" height="450">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/08-2014/2-black-wallpaper-pattern.preview.jpg" width="450" height="450">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
  </script>
```